# forcing a time between requests using - async/await delay

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

Have the following function "sendBulkProducts" that receives a array of objects (that are products) and using a API in this case of shopify and send a pair(2) of products for each second until it ends the loop. That is send two products waits one second then sends another two products waits one second and so on.

Using the package [delay](https://www.npmjs.com/package/delay)

But its not waiting the 1 second, so wanted to know what step in code is wrong?

```
 const sendBulkProducts = (products) => {
        const promisesArray = products.map( async (product,index) => {
            console.log(product);
            console.log('\n\n');
            console.log(index % 2);
            if(index % 2 !== 0){
                insertProductShopify({
                    "product":product
                });
                console.log('wait 1 seconds');
                return await delay(1000);
            }else{
                console.log('send away');
                return insertProductShopify({
                    "product":product
                });
            }
        });
        return Promise.all(promisesArray);
    }

const insertProductShopify = async product => {
  await request({
   .....
  });
}
```

Comment: hum haven't see what is the code of the package to force the delay...

Comment: `products.map` invoke all send.

Comment: I think you want to use `for (const product of products) { … }` instead of using `products.map`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`products.map` send all products in parallel, you need to iterate through them instead.

```
const sendBulkProducts = async(products) => {
  let index = 0
  for (let product of products) {
    insertProductShopify({product})
    if (++index % 2 == 0){
      await delay(1000)
    }
  }
}
```